# wordnet alternatives to find semantic relationships between words python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, semantics, wordnet

i have a project to get semantic relationships between two words , i want to get word to word relationships like hypernyms,hyponyms, Synonyms, holonyms, ...
i try wordnet nltk but most of relationships is none,
here is sample code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from wordhoard import synonyms

Word1 = 'red'
Word2 = 'color'
LSTWord1 =[]
for syn in wn.synsets(Word1):
    for lemma in syn.part_meronyms():
        LSTWord1.append(lemma)

            
for s in LSTWord1:
    if Word2 in s.name() :
        print(Word1 +' is meronyms  of ' +  Word2) 
        break
LSTWord2 =[]
for syn in wn.synsets(Word2):
    for lemma in syn.part_meronyms ():
        LSTWord2.append(lemma)

for s in LSTWord2:
    if Word1 in s.name() :
        print( Word2   +' is meronyms  of ' + Word1)
        break
```

here an example of words:

```
scheduled ,geometry
games,river
campaign,sea
adventure,place
session,road
long,town
campaign,road
session,railway
difficulty of session,place of interest
campaign,town
leader,historic place
have,town
player,town
skills,church
campaign,cultural interest
character name,town
player,monument
player,province
games,beach
expertise level,gas station
character,municipality
world,electrict line
social interaction,municipality
world,electric line
percentage,municipality
character,hospital
inhabitants,mine
active character,municipality
campaign,altitude
died,municipality
many time,mountain
adventurer,altitude
campaign,peak
gain,place of interest
new capabilities,cultural interest
player,cultural interest
achievement,national park
campaign,good
first action,railway station
player,province
```

may wordnet is limit or may there is no relation between words, my question is there any alternatives to wordnet to handle semantic relationships between words, or is there any better way to get semantic relation between words?
Thanks

Comment: Synonyms of these words is easy. But are any of your word pairs hypernyms, hyponyms or holonyms?

Comment: i want to get any possible relations between word pairs like hypernyms,hyponyms, Synonyms, holonyms, ...and other sematnic relations defined in wordnet

Comment: but i did not find any other libararies has these relations, so i just use wordnet

Comment: I wrote a python module called wordhoard that does antonyms, synonyms and definition.  I need to do some research on how to obtain the other sematnic relations, such as "red" is a hyponyms of color.   I have an idea, but it will required me to update wordhoard, which I was already working on for another feature.

Comment: Ok.  I did some research on this question.  So far I haven't found any solid way to determine homonyms and holonyms with any python module.  hyponyms are doable with some effort.  I will post an answer once I have written some code to do this.  It will take a bit to do.

Comment: FYI I'm in the process of updating the *wordhoard* module that you are using to perform some of the tasks that you want to accomplish.  I will post back here when I push the update.

Comment: How critical is it for you to have holonyms vs hyponyms and hypernyms?

Comment: Thank you, brother, I really appreciate your effort, but I was working on this project and it was required to deliver it in a certain period, so I used Wordnet and delivered the project with it. So now i done with it. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries.  I will still update the wordhoard module for others to use.

Answer (score 2):

As I previously stated, I'm the author of the Python package [wordhoard](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/wordhoard) that you used in your question.  Based on your question, I decided to add some additional modules to the package.  These modules focus on:

- homophones
- hypernyms
- hyponyms

I could not find an easy way to add the *meronyms,* but I'm still looking at the best way to do that.

*The homophones modules will query a hand-built list of 60,000+ most frequently used English words for known homophone.*  I plan to expand this list in the future.

```
from wordhoard import Homophones

words = ['scheduled' ,'geometry', 'games', 'river', 'campaign', 'sea', 'adventure','place','session', 'road', 'long', 'town', 'campaign', 'road', 'session', 'railway']
for word in words:
    homophone = Homophones(word)
    results = homophone.find_homophones()
    print(results)
    # output 
    no homophones for scheduled
    no homophones for geometry
    no homophones for games
    no homophones for river
    no homophones for campaign
    ['sea is a homophone of see', 'sea is a homophone of cee']
    no homophones for adventure
    ['place is a homophone of plaice']
    ['session is a homophone of cession']
    ['road is a homophone of rowed', 'road is a homophone of rode']
    truncated...
```

*The hypernyms module queries various online repositories.*

```
from wordhoard import Hypernyms

words = ['scheduled' ,'geometry', 'games', 'river', 'campaign','sea', 'adventure',
         'place','session','road', 'long','town', 'campaign','road', 'session', 'railway']
for word in words:
    hypernym = Hypernyms(word)
    results = hypernym.find_hypernyms()
    print(results)
    # output 
    ['no hypernyms found']
    ['arrangement', 'branch of knowledge', 'branch of math', 'branch of mathematics', 'branch of maths', 'configuration', 'figure', 'form', 'math', 'mathematics', 'maths', 'pure mathematics', 'science', 'shape', 'study', 'study of numbers', 'study of quantities', 'study of shapes', 'system', 'type of geometry']
    ['lake', 'recreation']
    ['branch', 'dance', 'fresh water', 'geological feature', 'landform', 'natural ecosystem', 'natural environment', 'nature', 'physical feature', 'recreation', 'spring', 'stream', 'transportation', 'watercourse']
    ['action', 'actively seek election', 'activity', 'advertise', 'advertisement', 'battle', 'canvass', 'crusade', 'discuss', 'expedition', 'military operation', 'operation', 'political conflict', 'politics', 'promote', 'push', 'race', 'run', 'seek votes', 'wage war']
    truncated...
```

*The hyponyms module queries repositories.*

```
from wordhoard import Hyponyms

words = ['scheduled' ,'geometry', 'games', 'river', 'campaign','sea', 'adventure',
         'place','session','road', 'long','town', 'campaign','road', 'session', 'railway']
for word in words:
    hyponym = Hyponyms(word)
    results = hyponym.find_hyponyms()
    print(results)
    # output 
    ['no hyponyms found']
    ['absolute geometry', 'affine geometry', 'algebraic geometry', 'analytic geometry', 'combinatorial geometry', 'descriptive geometry', 'differential geometry', 'elliptic geometry', 'euclidean geometry', 'finite geometry', 'geometry of numbers', 'hyperbolic geometry', 'non-euclidean geometry', 'perspective', 'projective geometry', 'pythagorean theorem', 'riemannian geometry', 'spherical geometry', 'taxicab geometry', 'tropical geometry']
    ['jack in the box', 'postseason']
    ['affluent', 'arkansas river', 'arno river', 'avon', 'big sioux river', 'bighorn river', 'brazos river', 'caloosahatchee river', 'cam river', 'canadian river', 'cape fear river', 'changjiang', 'chari river', 'charles river', 'chattahoochee river', 'cimarron river', 'colorado river', 'orange', 'red', 'tunguska']
    ['ad blitz', 'ad campaign', 'advertising campaign', 'agitating', 'anti-war movement', 'campaigning', 'candidacy', 'candidature', 'charm campaign', 'come with', 'electioneering', 'feminism', 'feminist movement', 'fund-raising campaign', 'fund-raising drive', 'fund-raising effort', 'military campaign', 'military expedition', 'political campaign', 'senate campaign']
    truncated...
```

Please let me know if you have any issues when you used these new modules.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for arbitrary semantic relationships between a pair of given words and in a large vocabulary. Probably simple cosine similarity of the word embedding can help here. You can start with [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).